# allocating memory with malloc()

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

In the program below I am trying to make the function insert() to allocate memory by calling `malloc()` to create a new struct (person)...but I get the following warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]...How should I use the malloc() function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* these arrays are just used to give the parameters to 'insert',
   to create the 'people' array 
*/

#define HOW_MANY 7
char *names[HOW_MANY]= {"Simon", "Suzie", "Alfred", "Chip", "John", "Tim",
              "Harriet"};
int ages[HOW_MANY]= {22, 24, 106, 6, 18, 32, 24};

typedef struct
{
  char *name;
  int age;
}person;


static void insert(person *p, char *name, int age) 
{
  p = (struct person *)malloc(sizeof(person));
  p->name = name;
  p->age = age;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{

  person people[7];

  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
  {
    insert (&people[i], names[i], ages[i]);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
  {
    printf ("name: %s, age: %i\n", people[i].name, people[i].age);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `struct person` and `person` are not the same. The first one doesn't even exist

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: @roderickyoung sure, mine's gone, too. :)

Answer (score 4):

You're casting the result of `malloc` to `struct person *`, but `p` is of type `person *`.  They are not the same thing.  The first is the tag name of a `struct` (which in this case doesn't exist) while the other is a `typedef` which aliases (in this case) an unnamed `struct`.

You actually [shouldn't be casting the result value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) as that can cause other errors.

Additionally, you shouldn't be using `malloc` at all.  You pass in the address of a `person` structure, so there is already memory allocated for it (i.e. as a local variable in `main`).

Get rid of the `malloc` and that will fix the issue.

Comment: When using malloc() with Visual C++ or Builder C++ compiler, I get always an error if the result value is not cast with the pointer type. Visual C++ 6.0 : `error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to '<Xxxx> *'`. Builder C++ XE10 :  `E2034 Impossible de convertir 'void *' en '<Xxxx> *'`.

Comment: @J.Piquard If you're using a C++ compiler, then yes you need to cast the result.  With a C compiler however, you should not.

Answer (score 1):

Have a closer look at your code.

```
person people[7];
```

`people` is an array of 7 elements of type `person`, where all the elements are allocated memory at compile time (*loosely speaking*), there's no need of run-time allocation here. You're won't be needing the `malloc()`, in first place.

That said, if you want dynamic allocation, then, you will need the `person` to be an array of 7 pointer variables to type `person` and you can allocate memory to the individual pointer inside the `insert()` function. Something like `person *people[7];` can be of use there. Also, you need to include `stdlib.h` to have the prototype of `malloc()` and family. That is one of the reasons for [why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

That way, your function prototype will also change. You have to

- accept a `person **p`
- operate on `(*p)` inside the `insert()` function, and finally,
- in `main()`, you have to use pointer member reference operator `->` while printing the values of individual elements.

Comment: I have to do this program as an assignment for uni...and in the task says to use malloc() in the insert() function...

Comment: @RalucaDamarisLupeş I have updated the answer, see if that helps.

Comment: what would be the syntax of printing the individual elements using ->?

Comment: I tried what you have suggested but I receive 2 errors

Comment: @RalucaDamarisLupeş `people[i]->name` and likewise.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, but it really depends on how you are gathering you're data. But with the array you have described it is possible this way.

Although, for you're specific situation, where you have declared `7` persons, it is best to not use `malloc()`. If you don't know how many persons there will be, then `malloc()` is a good choice.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define HOW_MANY 7

typedef struct{
   char *name;
  int age;
}person_t;

typedef struct {
    person_t *person;
    int numpersons;
} all_person_t;

all_person_t *initialize_persons(void);
void insert(all_person_t *persons, char *name, int age, int count);
void print_persons(all_person_t *persons);
void insert_each_person(all_person_t *persons, char *names[], int ages[]);
void free_persons(all_person_t *persons);

int
main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    char *names[HOW_MANY]= {"Simon", "Suzie", "Alfred", "Chip", "John", "Tim", "Harriet"};
    int ages[HOW_MANY]= {22, 24, 106, 6, 18, 32, 24};

    all_person_t *persons;

    persons = initialize_persons();

    insert_each_person(persons, names, ages);

    print_persons(persons);

    free_persons(persons);

    return 0;
}

void
insert_each_person(all_person_t *persons, char *names[], int ages[]) {
    int i;

    persons->person = malloc(persons->numpersons *sizeof(person_t));

    for (i = 0; i < persons->numpersons; i++) {
        insert(persons, names[i], ages[i], i);
    }
}

all_person_t
*initialize_persons(void) {
    all_person_t *persons;
    persons = malloc(sizeof(*persons));
    persons->numpersons = HOW_MANY;
    return persons;
}

void
insert(all_person_t *persons, char *name, int age, int count) {
    persons->person[count].name = malloc(strlen(name)+1);

    strcpy(persons->person[count].name, name);
    persons->person[count].age = age;
}

void
print_persons(all_person_t *persons) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < persons->numpersons; i++) {
         printf("%s %d\n", persons->person[i].name, persons->person[i].age);
    }
}

void
free_persons(all_person_t *persons) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < persons->numpersons; i++) {
        free(persons->person[i].name);
    }
    free(persons->person);
    free(persons);
}
```

Comment: @Raluca Damaris Lupeş does this help at all?